# How to format text cells in Jupyter?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I would like to create a Jupyter notebook to make a tutorial.

When I go to the jupyter website and I try jupyter in the browser, there is already a nice python tutorial, with some cells used as text explanations and others as code:

[image]

Now I create a new notebook and I am able to create different cells and format them in 4 types:

- Code
- Markdown
- Raw NBConvert
- Heading

However none of them allow me to create the text explanations with white background as in the image above.
I tried formatting one cell as markdown and it's just keeping with the grey background.

Am I missing something? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After creating those blocks you have to run them to give you that white background.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> inside the block.

For eg.

1. Click on a cell. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then press <kbd>1</kbd>
2. Now type this: "THIS IS A HEADING"
3. And then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You will get this as an output with a white background (The image below is a bit dull):

[image]

Comment: Wow, it's simpler than I though. Thanks

Comment: I would also suggest you use a python code formatter for Jupyter notebooks: https://github.com/kenkoooo/jupyter-autopep8.

Answer (score 1):

In addition, by using the `%%html` magic command, you can type HTML in cells and get them rendered the way you want